# Python - Split sorted string of characters when character is different than previous character

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split

I have a string of characters which I know to be sorted. Example:

```
myString = "aaaabbbbbbcccddddd"
```

I want to split this item into a list at the point when the character I am on is different than its preceding character, as shown below:

```
splitList = ["aaaa","bbbbbb","ccc","ddddd"]
```

I am working in Python 3.4.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, strange. I would have thought `re.split(r'(?<=(.))(?!\1)', "aaaabbbbbbcccddddd")` would work, but it does not. Can anyone better at Python explain why? (Edited for mispaste)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [294]: myString = "aaaabbbbbbcccddddd"

In [295]: [''.join(list(g)) for i,g in itertools.groupby(myString)]
Out[295]: ['aaaa', 'bbbbbb', 'ccc', 'ddddd']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myString = "aaaabbbbbbcccddddd"
result = []
for i,s in enumerate(myString):
    l = len(result)
    if  l == 0 or s != myString[i-1]:
        result.append(s)
    else:
        result[l-1] = result[l-1] + s

print result
```

Output:

```
['aaaa', 'bbbbbb', 'ccc', 'ddddd']
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on line 7 that "l" is undefined.